# BASH: comparar dos arrays con IF

Tags: linux, bash, script

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Comparo dos arrays, el primero es un fichero y el segundo array almacena los datos anteriores del primer array.
La idea es que al comparar los arrays no se cuele un dato repetido para realizar la operación una única vez.

Contenido del fichero a leer:

```
11.11.11.1
22.22.22.2
11.11.11.1
33.33.33.3
```

Contenido del script:

```
DATOS=( `cat archivo ` )
CONT5=${#DATOS[@]}
A="1"
for i in "$DATOS"
do

for (( i=0 ; i<$CONT5 ; i=i+1 )); do
    for (( r=0; r<$CONT5; r=r+1 )); do
if [ -z "${LOG[r]}" ]; then
    echo "Vacío" > /dev/null
    else

        if [ "$DATOS[i]" == "$LOG[r]" ] ;   then
        echo "" > /dev/null 
        echo "${DATOS[i]} ES IGUAL A ${LOG[r]} "
        A="0"
        else
        echo "${DATOS[i]} NO ES ${LOG[r]}"
        fi

    done
        if [ $A -eq 1 ] ; then
        echo "Realizar operación"
        fi
fi

    LOG[$i]=${DATOS[i]}
    A="1"
done
done
```

El problema es que compara "**11.11.11.1**" de `$DATOS` con "**11.11.11.1**" de `$LOG` y lo interpreta como cadenas diferentes.

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias

EDIT:
Después de añadir la línea de alo Malbarez el resultado del dump  es el siguiente:

```
Realizar operación
0000000   2   2   .   2   2   .   2   2   .   2       N   O       E   S
        062 062 056 062 062 056 062 062 056 062 040 116 117 040 105 123
0000020       1   1   .   1   1   .   1   1   .   1  \n
        040 061 061 056 061 061 056 061 061 056 061 012
0000034
Realizar operación
0000000   1   1   .   1   1   .   1   1   .   1       N   O       E   S
        061 061 056 061 061 056 061 061 056 061 040 116 117 040 105 123
0000020       1   1   .   1   1   .   1   1   .   1  \n
        040 061 061 056 061 061 056 061 061 056 061 012
0000034
0000000   1   1   .   1   1   .   1   1   .   1       N   O       E   S
        061 061 056 061 061 056 061 061 056 061 040 116 117 040 105 123
0000020       2   2   .   2   2   .   2   2   .   2  \n
        040 062 062 056 062 062 056 062 062 056 062 012
0000034
Realizar operación
0000000   3   3   .   3   3   .   3   3   .   3       N   O       E   S
        063 063 056 063 063 056 063 063 056 063 040 116 117 040 105 123
0000020       1   1   .   1   1   .   1   1   .   1  \n
        040 061 061 056 061 061 056 061 061 056 061 012
0000034
0000000   3   3   .   3   3   .   3   3   .   3       N   O       E   S
        063 063 056 063 063 056 063 063 056 063 040 116 117 040 105 123
0000020       2   2   .   2   2   .   2   2   .   2  \n
        040 062 062 056 062 062 056 062 062 056 062 012
0000034
0000000   3   3   .   3   3   .   3   3   .   3       N   O       E   S
        063 063 056 063 063 056 063 063 056 063 040 116 117 040 105 123
0000020       1   1   .   1   1   .   1   1   .   1  \n
        040 061 061 056 061 061 056 061 061 056 061 012
0000034
Realizar operación
```

EDIT2:
Con este parche funciona aunque sigo sin entender porque falla de la otra forma.

```
... Z=${DATOS[i]}
    X=${LOG[r]} 
    if [ "$Z" == "$X" ]; then
    #if [ "$DATOS[i]" == "$LOG[r]" ] ; then
...
```

EDIT3:
He probado ha limpiarlo como indicas en las respuesta pero no funciona.

```
...
    #Z=${DATOS[i]}
    #X=${LOG[r]}    
    #if [ "$Z" == "$X" ]; then
    LOGCLEAN=${LOG[r]//[$'\t\r\n']}
    echo "LOGCLEAN: $LOGCLEAN"
    if [ "$DATOS[i]" == "$LOGCLEAN" ] ; then
...
```

El resultado se repite:

```
Realizar operación
0000000   2   2   .   2   2   .   2   2   .   2       N   O       E   S
        062 062 056 062 062 056 062 062 056 062 040 116 117 040 105 123
0000020       1   1   .   1   1   .   1   1   .   1  \n
        040 061 061 056 061 061 056 061 061 056 061 012
0000034
Realizar operación
0000000   1   1   .   1   1   .   1   1   .   1       N   O       E   S
        061 061 056 061 061 056 061 061 056 061 040 116 117 040 105 123
0000020       1   1   .   1   1   .   1   1   .   1  \n
        040 061 061 056 061 061 056 061 061 056 061 012
0000034
0000000   1   1   .   1   1   .   1   1   .   1       N   O       E   S
        061 061 056 061 061 056 061 061 056 061 040 116 117 040 105 123
0000020       2   2   .   2   2   .   2   2   .   2  \n
        040 062 062 056 062 062 056 062 062 056 062 012
0000034
Realizar operación
0000000   3   3   .   3   3   .   3   3   .   3       N   O       E   S
        063 063 056 063 063 056 063 063 056 063 040 116 117 040 105 123
0000020       1   1   .   1   1   .   1   1   .   1  \n
        040 061 061 056 061 061 056 061 061 056 061 012
0000034
0000000   3   3   .   3   3   .   3   3   .   3       N   O       E   S
        063 063 056 063 063 056 063 063 056 063 040 116 117 040 105 123
0000020       2   2   .   2   2   .   2   2   .   2  \n
        040 062 062 056 062 062 056 062 062 056 062 012
0000034
0000000   3   3   .   3   3   .   3   3   .   3       N   O       E   S
        063 063 056 063 063 056 063 063 056 063 040 116 117 040 105 123
0000020       1   1   .   1   1   .   1   1   .   1  \n
        040 061 061 056 061 061 056 061 061 056 061 012
0000034
Realizar operación
```

EDIT FINAL:
Aquí dejo el script funcional:

```
A="1" #El primer dato es aceptado aunque no haya comparación con $LOG
DATOS=( `cat archivo ` )
CONT5=${#DATOS[@]}
for i in "$DATOS"
do

    for (( i=0 ; i<$CONT5 ; i=i+1 )); do
        for (( r=0; r<$CONT5; r=r+1 )); do
            if [ -z "${LOG[r]}" ]; then
                echo "Vacío" > /dev/null
            else

                if [ "${DATOS[i]}" == "${LOG[r]}" ] ;   then
                    #echo "${DATOS[i]} ES IGUAL A ${LOG[r]} "
                    A="0"
                else
                    echo "" > /dev/null
                    #echo "${DATOS[i]} NO ES ${LOG[r]}"
                fi
                    fi
                        done
                        if [ $A -eq 1 ] ; then
                            echo "Realizar operación"
                        fi

                        LOG[$i]=${DATOS[i]}
                        A="1"
                    done
                done
```

El hecho de bloquear la operación en el caso de que se encuentre una coincidencia es que cuando se opera con un archivo que tiene muchos ítems, y algunos se repiten, se debe filtrar por coincidencia para evitar un mal filtrado. Se puede hacer la prueba en este último script plenamente funcional.

Gracias a todos por las respuestas

Comment: se estará colando un `newline`?

Comment: prueba con `echo "${DATOS[i]} NO ES ${LOG[r]}" | od -cb` eso te dara un dump de cada cadena y te puede dar una pista de si hay algun caracter no visible que se está colando en alguno de los valores comparados

Comment: alo Malbarez creo que si detecta el salto de línea. Esta es una parte del resultado del dump: Realizar operación
0000000   2   2   2   2   2       N   O       E   S       1   1   1   1
        062 062 062 062 062 040 116 117 040 105 123 040 061 061 061 061
0000020   1  \n
        061 012
0000022   ****Se ve fatal aquí pero sale "\n". No sé si este el fallo al que te refieres.****

Comment: agrega el dump a la pregunta y vemos como filtrarlo

Comment: es raro, el `\n` al final pareciera ser del `echo`

Comment: Se repite el "040" al inicio de cada ${LOG[r]} y no sé si eso puede ser lo que origine el error

Comment: es el espacio entre la S y el 1

Comment: Con esta chapuza funciona. Lo agrego a la pregunta. No sé por qué directamente no lo compara bien

Comment: creo q es por que `"$DATOS[i]"` se expande a lo que tenga `$DATOS` + `[i]` como cadena, en cambio `"${DATOS[i]}"` toma el elemento `i` del array `$DATOS`

Comment: Sí, podría ser. He probado lo que has puesto en tu respuesta, te respondo en la pregunta mejor.

Comment: va la respuesta correcta con prueba de ejemplo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si quieres que no se repita una operación con un dato procesado anteriormente esto es lo que necesitas:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Declaracion de variables
declare -a DATOS
declare -a LOG
declare -i z
declare -i y

# Asignar valos a variables
DATOS=$( cat archivo )
LOG="null" # Valor incial para que entre al bucle la primera vez, se sobreescribe la primera vez
z=0 # Contador
y=0 # Comprobación de si un valor es igual a otro

# Bucle del array DATOS
for i in ${DATOS}; do
    # Logitud del array LOG, es variable, se redefine cada vez que entra en el bucle
    CONT5=${#LOG[@]}
    # Bucle del array LOG
    for (( r=0; r<$CONT5; r=r+1 )); do
        # Comprueba que el valor de del array de DATOS es igual al de LOG
        if [ "${i}" == "${LOG[$r]}" ]; then
                echo "${i} ES IGUAL A ${LOG[$r]}"
                # Si $r es igual a un valor anterior finaliza el bucle
                r=$CONT5
                y=1
            fi
    done
    # Se almacena el en array de LOG el valor de DATOS anteriormente comprobado
    if [ $y -ne 1 ]; then
        LOG[$z]=${i}
        echo "${i} NO ES ${LOG[$r]}"
        echo "Realizar operacion"
    fi
    y=0
    # Aumentar el contador que usamos para el array LOG
    z=$((z + 1))
done
```

El bucle "for i in $ARRAY" recorre todo el array, independientemente del numero de items que contenga, por lo que el segundo bucle de "for i=0" no hace falta, además esta machacando el $i del bucle anterior.

Dentro de bucle "for in" usamos $i, para identificar el valor del array que comprobamos.

El arrays de LOG almacena todos los datos anteriormente comprobados, si ya se ha ejecutado la operación con ese valor no se hace nada, por eso el "Realizar operacion" debe ir en el "else" que es cuando no se ha ejecutado.

Comment: No, pruebe el código que he puesto como solución en la pregunta principal. Si se realiza la operación en cuando es distinto habrá errores. Dado que pueden haber 100 ítems que comparar (y se repitan) lo correcto es bloquear la operación en cuanto hay una sola coincidencia, y si no, que se se ejecute la operación.

Comment: Acabo de añadir la corrección para que cuando encuentre una condición de igualdad se salga del bucle y no lo almacene en el array de LOG.

Comment: Como añadido indicarte que en tu script tienes 3 bucles anidados (uno dentro del otro), eso queire decir que si tienes 4 valores ejecuta el codido 4 X 4 X 4, 3 elevado al cubo cuando lo normal serían dos bucles 4 X 4. El else de "NO ES" lo puedes eliminar si realmente no usas.

Comment: Con esta última edición lo que consigue es que la comparación de los arrays este mal realizada. Voy a dejarlo aquí, tiene el script plenamente funcional en la pregunta principal. Gracias por contestar.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

El tema está en como se expanden los parámetros en la comparación, ejemplo :

```
$ array[0]=01234567890abcdefgh
$ echo "|$array[0]|"
|01234567890abcdefgh[0]|
$ echo "|${array[0]}|"
|01234567890abcdefgh|

$ array[1]=${array[0]}
$ echo "|${array[1]}|"
|01234567890abcdefgh|


$ if [ "$array[0]" == "$array[1]" ]; then echo "SI"; else echo "NO"; fi
NO
$ if [ "${array[0]}" == "${array[1]}" ]; then echo "SI"; else echo "NO"; fi
SI
```

En tu caso estás comparando `"$DATOS[i]" == "$LOG[r]"` y debiera ser `"${DATOS[i]}" == "${LOG[r]}"`.

**dejo la respuesta original aqui**

Según el dump pareciera que el extra `\n` es parte del `echo` pero por las dudas limpiaría `$LOG` con [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). Incluyo como en la referencia `tabs '\t'`, `newlines '\n'` y `carriagreturns '\r'`.

```
LOGCLEAN=${LOG//[$'\t\r\n']}
```

ejemplo:

```
$ LOG=$'111.111.111.111\n'
$ echo "|$LOG|"
|111.111.111.111
|
$ LOGCLEAN=${LOG//[$'\t\r\n']}
$ echo "|$LOGCLEAN|"
|111.111.111.111|

$ echo "$LOG" | od -cb
0000000   1   1   1   .   1   1   1   .   1   1   1   .   1   1   1  \n
        061 061 061 056 061 061 061 056 061 061 061 056 061 061 061 012
0000020  \n
        012
0000021

$ echo "$LOGCLEAN" | od -cb
0000000   1   1   1   .   1   1   1   .   1   1   1   .   1   1   1  \n
        061 061 061 056 061 061 061 056 061 061 061 056 061 061 061 012
0000020
```

referencia:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19347380/1423096

Comment: Eso es. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Otra posible solución seria enfocar el problema de otra manera. Leer primero el fichero pasandole un filtro uniq (de manera que solo salen las lineas no repetidas) y acto seguido proceder con tu analisis. Esto seria:

```
#!/bin/bash
filelines=`cat archivo.txt | uniq`
for line in $filelines ; do
    echo $line
done
```

con lo anterior recorres todas las lineas del archivo.txt que NO estan repetidas (debido al uniq) y dentro del bucle imprime cada linea.

En tu caso, el echo $line lo cambiaria por el proceso que haces

Comment: Gracias por la idea ;)